# How to get order_increment_id using SOAP API in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, soap-api-v1

In Magento 1, we get the 'order_increment_id' when we use the 'order_creditmemo.info' parameter in SOAP API.

The same thing I want to fetch in Magento 2 SOAP API. But when I am trying to get order_increment_id by using 'salesCreditmemoRepositoryV1'. It does not return the 'order_increment_id'.

Can someone please help me to get 'order_increment_id' by using any other Repository?

```
$response = $request->salesCreditmemoRepositoryV1GetList(array('searchCriteria' => ''));

    $fullData = objectToArray($response);

    function objectToArray($d) {
    if (is_object($d)) {
        // Gets the properties of the given object
        // with get_object_vars function
        $d = get_object_vars($d);
    }

    if (is_array($d)) {
        /*
        * Return array converted to object
        * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
        * for recursive call
        */
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
    }
    else {
        // Return array
        return $d;
    }
} 
$creditmemos = $fullData['result']['items']['item'];

      foreach ($creditmemos as $creditmemo) {
                $response1 = $request->salesCreditmemoRepositoryV1Get(array('id' => $creditmemo['incrementId']));
                 $fullMemoResult = $this->objectToArray($response1);
                echo "<pre>";print_r($fullMemoeResult);
            }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface in construct of your class.

Then try this one,

```
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
$orderIncrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
```