# How to Get order increment id using order id in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order

Can anyone please tell me How to Get order increment id using order id in Magento 2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to pass `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` in construct of your class.

```
protected $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
    ..., 
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
){
    ...
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}
```

Then you can do following:

```
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
$orderIncrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.

Can you please tell me how can I get the order_increment_id by using 'salesCreditmemoRepositoryV1' in SOAP API. 

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127613/how-to-get-order-increment-id-using-soap-api-in-magento-2

Comment: You mean by using `<route url="/V1/creditmemo/:id" method="GET">`?

Comment: Please check here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127613/how-to-get-order-increment-id-using-soap-api-in-magento-2

I have added code snippet. 
What i am trying to do is: First getting all the credit memo list by using 'salesCreditmemoRepositoryV1GetList' after that I am using 'salesCreditmemoRepositoryV1Get' for getting the information about each credit memo by passing ''$creditmemo['incrementId']' .
Now the problem is I am not getting the order_increment_id in $fullMemoResult array. Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: In each credit memo you should have `order_id` also. With it you can do as in my answer :)

Comment: Hi, But I have this PHP file, out of magento root directory. So Can I do it with above code?

Answer (score 0):

This may help if you don't want to edit the `_construct` function:

```
private static function getIncrementIDfromOrderID($orderID) {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('sales_order'); //gives table name with prefix

    //Select Data from table
    $result = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT increment_id FROM " . $tableName . " WHERE entity_id = " . $orderID);
    if (count($result)) {
        return $result[0]['increment_id'];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

The best (optimized) way to get order id i.e `sales_order.increment_id` from entity id by creating a custom DB query in Magento2.

1. Create a `GetIncrementIdByOrderId` class:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types =1);

namespace Adapttive\SalesOrder\Model\Order;

use Exception;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order as OrderResource;

/**
 * Class GetIncrementIdByOrderId: To get order.entity_id by order.increment_id
 * Reference from \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderIncrementIdChecker
 */
class GetIncrementIdByOrderId
{
    /**
     * @var OrderResource
     */
    private $resource;

    /**
     * @param OrderResource $resource
     */
    public function __construct(OrderResource $resource)
    {
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    /**
     * Get order increment id by order id.
     *
     * @param int $orderId
     * @return int|string
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function get($orderId)
    {
        $result = "";

        try {
            /** @var  \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $adapter */
            $adapter = $this->resource->getConnection();
            $bind = [':entity_id' => $orderId];
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select */
            $select = $adapter->select();
            $select->from($this->resource->getMainTable(), "increment_id")
                ->where('entity_id = :entity_id');
            $incrementId = $adapter->fetchOne($select, $bind);
            if (!empty($incrementId)) {
                $result = (string)$incrementId;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $result = "";
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

2. Usage:

```php
$orderIncrementId = $this->getIncrementIdByOrderId->get($orderId)
```

Reference: https://adapttive.com/blog/magento-2-get-order-id-by-increment-id/